# How to add SQL Server Analysis Services instance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I have installed SQL Server with SQL Server management, but when I want to go to the Analysis server instance, there is no one.

I checked the SQL Server management but there is no Analysis Services process to enable.
I went to the SQL Server 2019 setup to add the Analysis server feature but it's not showing to install.

[image: SQL Server Setup Wizzard]

What can I do?

Comment: That's the installerr, not "SQL Server management". Which edition are you trying to install? [All versions except Express and Web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/analysis-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server-2016?view=asallproducts-allversions) have Analysis Services. For development, you can use the free Developer edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I had to do a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

The screen shot in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/install-windows/install-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions) shows "Analysis services"

[image]

But, since it is missing for you, I am guessing, you have selected an different edition of SQL Server 2019 setup (Web edition, may be ?).

If you using it as Developer, try the developer edition of SQL 2019 setup.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

[image]